# symfony 1.4 display images as choices in choice widget

Tags: symfony1, widget, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form with a certain choice widget (DoctrineChoice). The choices refer to certain image file in the server, and I use the expander=true option (for checkboxes/radiobuttons)

Is there a way to display the widget by displaying the images of each option? By default, I get only the id of the options in the database.

Using firebug, I noticed that the generated HTML has a  tag with the id of each choice, and also, I managed to change this with a certain image, so I'm guessing that I all need to do is to change the text for the label of each choice. Even though, the 'label' option of the widget just changes the label for the whole select, so that won't do...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of research, I have managed some kind of solution, but maybe there's something more correct?

Instead of using a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice, I used a sfWidgetFormSelectRadio (but Checkbox can do too, but I don't know if it can work with other widgets, or even select widgets too :/ just because my business rules require it, a SelectRadio was sufficient in this particular case...)

The choices option of the widget was filled with the results of the previous query I was using to fill the previous DoctrineChoice widget, previously processed so the Id of each record was the key and value of each choice:

```
$imgs = Doctrine_Core::getTable('ProjImages')->getImages();
$choices = array('' => '');
foreach ($imgs as $img):
  $choices[$img->getId()] = $img->getId();
endforeach;
```

Next, I also passed the 'formatter' option to the widget:

```
$this->widgetSchema['img'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(array(
                    'choices' => $choices,
                    'formatter' => array($this, 'showAsImages')
                                ));
$this->validatorSchema['img'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
                     'choices' => $choices,
                     'required' => false
                     ));
```

I used the 'required'=>false option in the validator since I also need the option to select 'no image' in my widget, which is reflected in the $choices array as the first ('' => '') choice.

Finally, I wrote the formatter callback:

```
public function showAsImages($widget, $inputs)
{
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($inputs as $input)
  {
    $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
    $domdoc->loadHTML($input['label']);
    $node = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0);
    if ($node->nodeValue != "")
    {
      $img = Doctrine_Core::getTable('ProjImages')->find(array($node->nodeValue));
      $input['label'] = '<label '.$node->attributes->item(0)->name .
                        '="'.$node->attributes->item(0)->value.'">' .
                        '<img src="'.$img->getImg().'" alt="image" />' .
                        '</label>';
    }
    $rows[] = $widget->renderContentTag('li',
                    $input['input'].
                    $widget->getOption('label_separator').
                    $input['label']);
  }
  return $widget->renderContentTag('ul',
                       implode($widget->getOption('separator'), $rows),
                       array('class' => $widget->getOption('class')));
}
```

I used the source code for the original default formatter of the sfWidgetFormSelectRadio and based on it, I modified the 'label' of each input element (all the rest of the code is exactly the same as the source code I used).

And for the label of each input element, I used the DOMDocument object to get the value (id of the image), then make a DB query to get the image, and then re-assemble the 'label' with the < img > tag...  Of course, if I happen to find the empty choice, I use the default 'label'...

And that was it... I think the formatter callback can get some more work, so any suggestions, or even better solutions to the problem, are welcomed... As you can see, I depend on the 'formatter' option of the widget, and as far a I can see, only some widgets accept this option...

Thanks for reading!